# Shooting a projectile in a 2d-space

Tags: trigonometry

Okay, I struggled a bit choosing wheter to put this on StackOverflow or here, Math. I concluded that it was actual math my problem and not "exactly" programming.

You see, I am making a 2d game, top-view where your character moves around and you can use your mouse as aim to shoot.

My problem is that I can't figure out the correct formula to get the "amount of pixels to move per frame". Let me explain:

The projectile being shot will not "stop" at the point your mouse clicked. Instead it will continuously move. Every frame, my projectile is supposed to "change X-position by {pixels}" and "change Y-position by {pixels}". I don't know how to figure out the {pixels} amount I need for both X and Y movements.

Here is some code. It is quite self-explanatory:

```
class PortalBall
  def initialize(sx,sy,dx,dy)     # sx,sy source points. dx,dy destination points
    @speed = 60
    x_per_frame = dx / @speed
    y_per_frame = dy / @speed
  end
  def update
    @sprite.x += x_per_frame
    @sprite.y += y_per_frame
  end
end
```

As you can see, my formula to figure out the amount of x pixels to move per frame is "destination X divided by speed". Speed is always 60 actually...

But this clearly isn't working properly. Can someone help me fixing my formula?

**NOTE**
In this language, the higher on the screen means **less** Y position and the lower screen is **more** Y position. The top of the screen is Y 0, and the bottom is Y 600.

Comment: maybe you want to calculate the unit vector going into the direction of your bullet. Then every time step $t$ move $t$ times the unit vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, whenever you have `dx` you actually want `dx-sx` and similarly for y. That's because you don't care about the absolute position of the destination, just the relative position of the source and the destination.

But your code is a little confused. Right now, if you increase `@speed`, the projectile moves *slower.* Also, if you increase the distance from the source to the destination, the projectile moves faster. I assume what you actually want is for the projectile to move at `@speed` regardless of the distance between the source and destination.

In that case, you want something like the following.

`@speed = 60

dist = Sqrt[(dx-sx)^2+(dy-sy)^2]

x_per_frame = (dx-sx)/dist * @speed

y_per_frame = (dy-sy)/dist * @speed`

(I'm not sure what square roots look like in your language.) The point of dividing by `dist` is to normalize the displacement vector so that it's a unit vector. You should probably also make some things floats as necessary to prevent rounding error.

Comment: Qiaochu: By "floats", maybe you meant "doubles" (i.e., double precision)?

Comment: Sure. Whatever makes the gun not miss.

Comment: Hmm... there are some scenarios the square root line throws me an error because the value I am giving it is negative. What do I do I that case? Also yeah, I want the bullet's speed to be the same no matter the distance between the mouse and the character, but I'm not sure of that either.

Comment: The value of $(dx-sx)^2 + (dy-sy)^2$ should never be negative. Are you sure you wrote that correctly?

Comment: sx = 438, sy = 298, dx = 256, dy = 227. The value is -253. The code line is dist = Math.sqrt(((dx-sx)^2)+((dy-sy)^2))

Comment: The correct value is $38165$. Maybe your language is not interpreting ^ correctly; by this I mean exponentiation. (Also, you need an extra parenthesis at the end.) Maybe you should just write it as dist = Math.sqrt((dx-sx)*(dx-sx) + (dy-sy)*(dy-dy)).

Comment: Ah! I was using the wrong operator. Thank you! It is working perfectly now! If you feel curious, here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906080/problem-with-math

Answer (score 0):

I will add to Qiaochu Yuan's answer that you'll probably want the (dx-sx) and (dy-sy) to be an absolute value. Otherwise you'll move in the opposite direction if (dx < sx) or if (dy < sy).

Here's my working example in Java:

```
float dist = (float) Math.sqrt( Math.pow((toX -fromX), 2) + Math.pow((toY -fromY), 2));

speedX = Math.abs(toX - fromX)/dist * speed ;
speedY = Math.abs(toY - fromY)/dist * speed ;
```